# Java. Regular Expression. How Parse?

Tags: java, regex

As input parameters I can have two types of String:

```
codeName=SomeCodeName&codeValue=SomeCodeValue
```

or

```
codeName=SomeCodeName
```

without `codeValue`.

`codeName` and `codeValue` are the keys.

How can I use regular expression to return the key's values? In this example it would return only `SomeCodeName` and `SomeCodeValue`.

Comment: would your SomeCodeName and SomeCodeValue
 may contain & or = ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with a regex for that. [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with simple tokens ('&', '=') will do the job.

```
String[] args = inputParams.split("&");
for (String arg: args) {
    String[] split = arg.split("=");
    String name = split[0];
    String value = split[1];
}
```

Comment: Check out Guava's `Splitter.MapSplitter`

Comment: +1, but I think you should change `arg.split("=")` to `arg.split("=", 2)`, since equals-signs are allowed in the values of query-string parameters.

Comment: Note that Argument to String.split is a regex

Comment: You might need to consider using `Pattern` as new pattern gets created in every iteration when arg.split("=") is used

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Guava's [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

```
String myinput = "...";
Map<String, String> mappedValues = 
           Splitter.on("&")
                   .withKeyValueSeparator("=")
                   .split(myinput);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to split the source string first and then to run 2 separate regular expressions against 2 parts.

```
Pattern pCodeName = Pattern.compile("codeName=(.*)");
Pattern pCodeValue = Pattern.compile("codeValue=(.*)");

String[] parts = str.split("\\&");
Matcher m = pCodeName.matcher(parts[0]);
String codeName = m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;

String codeValue = null;
if (parts.length > 1) {
    m = pCodeValue.matcher(parts[1]);
    codeValue = m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
}
```

}

But if you want you can also say:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("codeName=(\\w+)(\\&codeValue=(\\w+))?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

String codeName = null;
String codeValue = null;

if (m.find()) {
    codeName = m.group(1);
    codeValue = m.groupCount() > 1 ? m.group(2) : null;
}
```

Comment: IMO Second option is better as it would be a stricter match